# Media3 with Exoplayer gives me Soure Error

Tags: android, kotlin, mp3, exoplayer

I am trying to make a simple app to catch data (mp3) from api

https://server16.mp3quran.net/nufais/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/036.mp3

When I use this url in media3 exo player >> gives me source Error

And when I use another audio.mp3
The code runs correctly.

I tried to use another api and the code runs but I need to use this api that give me source error
How can I fix this ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.